# Eigenvalues of sum of transpositions

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to solve certain problems on the classifications of some sort graphs. I need to calculate or extract some information about the eigenvalues of a certain sum of transpositions (that are the applications which exchange two base vectors).

Let $H$ be a Hilbert Space whose a base is $\{e_i\}$.

Let $A_{ij}$ be the application $H\rightarrow H$ that exchanges $e_i$ and $e_j$.

Then I take the sum of $A_{ij}$ over the couples $(i,j)$ that are the edges of the graph.

I need to find, given the number of edges fixed, the form of graph that maximizes the second largest eigevalues of this sum. (the largest one is always $1$)

Comment: Largest eigenvalue is not necessarily $1$.  For example, take the graph of a triangle with a disconnected point adjoined.

Comment: Indeed my reasoning is not well enough. I've found that there are already many researches in this field of Graph Theory, whose the main focuses are the Laplacien matrix and the adjacency matrix of a graph. I think I'm not in the right position to advance in my limited time resource. Thanks for the correction!